# Ionide F# - Lint all files

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

I am using Ionide F# in VS Code. When I open `.fs` files, I see items added to the VS Code `Problems` tab and editor highlighting to show the problems. However, I cannot figure out how to lint the entire solution. How do I lint all files?

---

**Edit:**

Here is the repository where I am experiencing this issue: 
https://github.com/GamesFaix/Djambi3

Here is an example `fsproj` file from the repository, where I am experiencing this issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Errors.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Context.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Security.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Pieces.fs" />
    <Compile Include="ModelExtensions\BoardModelExtensions.fs" />
    <Compile Include="ModelExtensions\BoardModelUtility.fs" />
    <Compile Include="ModelExtensions\GameModelExtensions.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\NotificationService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\UserService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\SessionService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\BoardService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\GameCrudService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\PlayerService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\SelectionOptionsService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\SelectionService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\GameStartService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\EventService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\IndirectEffectsService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\TurnService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\PlayerStatusChangeService.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Managers\BoardManager.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Managers\GameManager.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Managers\SessionManager.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Managers\SnapshotManager.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Managers\UserManager.fs" />
    <Compile Include="LogicRoot.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\api.common\api.common.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\api.db.interfaces\api.db.interfaces.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\api.logic.interfaces\api.logic.interfaces.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\api.model\api.model.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="..\..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Perhaps tell people what language support extension do you use.

Comment: I am trying to use Ionide in VS Code. I originally installed F# w/ Visual Studio 2017 using the 'F# Language Support', module.

Comment: Do you have an fsproj file?